# When I Call a Window From an Another Form, It Shows Two Windows One on the Top of the Other

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have two forms: Form A and Form B. Canvas "Home" belongs to Form A and there are two buttons on it. I want to call "Window 1" on Form B when I push first button and call "Window 2" on Form B if I push second button.

Now, if I push first button, I see Window 1. But if I push second button, I see Window 2 on the top of the Window 1. Why?

This is second button's 'WHEN-PUSH-BUTTON' trigger. (First button's 'WHEN-PUSH-BUTTON' trigger is the same) :

```
DECLARE
   user_form       VARCHAR2 (100);
   param_list_id   paramlist;
BEGIN     

   :parameter.PRMTR := '2';  

   param_list_id := CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST ('param_data');

   ADD_PARAMETER (param_list_id,
              'PRMTR',
              text_parameter,
              TO_CHAR ( :parameter.PRMTR));


   user_form := '/home/oracle/program/formb.fmx';


   CALL_FORM (user_form,
          hide,
          do_replace,
          no_query_only,
          param_list_id);          

   DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST ('param_data');

END;
```

And this is 'WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE' trigger of Form B:

```
IF :parameter.PRMTR = '2' THEN          


    GO_BLOCK('DATABLOCK_TWO');


ELSIF :parameter.PRMTR = '1' THEN

    GO_BLOCK('DATABLOCK_ONE');


END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of opening Window 1 in any case is that datablock of Window 1 is on top of all data blocks.

As far as i understand to call two separate window from another form is not possible in this way. I created a home window on Form B and moved buttons on it. I called this home window from Form A. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the when-new-form-instance trigger of form B a `HIDE_VIEW` command to hide the first window.

Comment: It shows Window 2  before goes into when-new-form-instance. Although I know this, I tried it and it didn't work. I guess this problem is related to data block/canvas/window properties. But I didn't find it.